# Optimize hierarchy query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, hierarchical-data

Table "links" contains 2 columns : PARENT_CODE, CHILD_CODE

> ```
> PARENT_CODE | CHILD_CODE 
> ------------|------------
> A1          | B1 
> A1          | B2
> B1          | C1 
> B1          | C2 
> B2          | C3 
> B3          | C3
> C3          | D1
> ```

This table eventually used to form following graph :

[image: node structure]

My question will be how to write optimized hierarchy query in Oracle to get the full graph connected, and the input parameter will be any of node.

To illustrate the input/output, this is simplified SQL :
SELECT PARENT_CODE,CHILD_CODE FROM {HIERARCHY QUERY} where NODE = {ANY NODE}

Comment: I know there's hierarchical query in oracle, but it will not give all connected node.

Comment: You can use connect by to do this.  Select parent_code, child_code, level  from links connect by prior child_code = parent_code.  It will do a left tree walk and also provide a pseudo column with the level (depth) that it is currently evaluating.  To make this work with any performance at all, both columns must be indexed (independently).  WHOOPS - if B3 is not a child of A1, this breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below with show you all links. The idea is that first I create two ways connection between nodes. Using it we can do recursive query that returns our results. The last thing is decode that returns who is real parent and who is child basing on dir (0 - means original direction, 1 - means reverted direction).

```
with linkT (parent_code, child_code) as 
(select 'A1','B1' from dual union all
 select 'A1','B2' from dual union all
 select 'B1','C1' from dual union all
 select 'B1','C2' from dual union all
 select 'B2','C3' from dual union all
 select 'B3','C3' from dual union all
 select 'C3','D1' from dual union all
 select 'E1','F1' from dual ),
T1 as (
select parent_code, child_code, 0 Dir from linkT
union all 
select child_code, parent_code, 1 Dir from linkT )
select distinct 
       decode(dir, 0, parent_code, child_code) as Parent_code,
       decode(dir, 0, child_code, parent_code) as Child_Code
from (
select parent_code, child_code, dir
from T1 x
start with x.child_code='A1'
connect by nocycle prior x.parent_code=x.child_code ) 
order by 1,2
```

Comment: This is brilliant and exactly what I needed !